# How to add to spotify playlist using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest, spotify

I want to be able to add songs to a users playlist on spotify. To play songs, it wasnt necessary to use their api, I just had to add:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=spotify:user:spotify:playlist:3rgsDhGHZxZ9sB9DQWQfuf" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

which connects/checks already if user is logged in on spotify. Is there any way to add songs to playlist without using the api (asking because it also wasn't needed to play songs for logged in users)? If I have to use their api, I found the following url endpoint:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks
```

I am not quite sure how to get the users id since the user was connected automatically, using only the iframe provided by spotify. I tried to find something online but couldn't and the tutorial on spotifys website uses nodejs. If I have to use their api, how could I do that using only javascript? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the API to add songs to a user's playlist.

To get the user's ID, you need to authenticate the user through one of the [authorization flows described here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/), and use the [current user endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/). You can event [get the user's playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists/) directly using the API.

If you're struggling with the sample code, try out the client-side Javascript wrapper here: https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I def. have to authenticate the user using the spotify api, even though that authentication happens automatically when I use spotify's iframe?!

Comment: Yes, you do. There are no widgets for adding to a playlist.